# How do I access column data in a previous select statement from a sub-query?

Tags: mysql

**PROBLEM**

How do I access column data in a previous select statement from a sub-query?

Below is a simple mock up of what I'm attempting to do.

Tables used: Quotes, Users

**QUOTES TABLE**

qid, (quote id)

owner_uid,

creator_uid

**SQL SYNTAX:**

```
SELECT q.qid, q.owner_uid, q.creator_uid, owner.fname, owner.lname 
FROM quotes q, 
(SELECT u.fname, u.lname FROM users u WHERE u.uid = q.owner_uid) AS owner 
WHERE q.qid = '#'
```

**SUMMARY**

I want to be able to use the quote table's owner_uid and specify it for the owner table so I can return all the owner info for that particular quote.

The problem is, q.owner_uid is not recognized in the owner sub-query. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd be better off using a JOIN than a subquery in this case:

```
SELECT q.qid, q.owner_uid, q.creator_uid, u.fname, u.lname 
FROM quotes q 
JOIN users u ON u.uid = q.owner_uid 
WHERE q.qid = '#'
```

Comment: My answer addresses the subsquery issue, but I actually prefer the answer from @djacobson over my own answer

Comment: I'll probably end up using your solution, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

While I like djacobson's solution more, it doesn't directly answer the question.

I found that MySQL user defined variables does the job.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

MySQL variables allow for cross statement data access...

I saved the owner's uid into a variable called owner_uid and stuck that variable in place of q.owner_uid.

This is how I access column data in a previous SELECT statement.

```
SELECT q.qid, @owner_uid:=q.owner_uid, q.creator_uid, owner.fname, owner.lname 
FROM quotes q, 
(SELECT u.fname, u.lname FROM users u WHERE u.uid = @owner_uid) AS owner 
WHERE q.qid = '#'
```